# Implicit conversion to pointer

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operator-keyword, implicit-conversion

I have this chunk of code:

```
struct A
{
    operator int*() { return nullptr; }
};
int main()
{
    A x;
    x[42] = 42;
    int z = x[42];
}
```

To my surprise, the following compiles. The implicit conversion takes place and conditionally converts `A` to `int*` and accesses the memory given by the pointer (I returned `nullptr` just for simplicity). As the [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion) says:

*Implicit conversions are performed whenever an expression of some type T1 is used in context that does not accept that type, but accepts some other type T2; in particular:*

- *when the expression is used as an operand with an operator that expects T2*

So, why does the following not work?

```
struct A
{
    int operator[](int)
    {
        return 42;    
    }
};

struct B
{
    operator A()
    {
        return A();
    }
};

int main()
{
    B x;
    int z = x[42];
    x[42] = 42;
}
```

The compiler says: `error: no match for 'operator[]' (operand types are 'B' and 'int')`. What am i missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These automatic conversions are not applied before calling a member function. A nice example for this is the following

```
struct A {
    bool operator<(int) const {
        return true;
    }
};

bool operator>(const A &, int) {
    return false;
}

struct B {
    operator A() {
        return A();
    }
};

int main() {
    B b;
    auto z1 = b > 5;  // Works; calls operator<(B::operator A(), int)
    auto z2 = b < 5;  // Compile error; tries to call B::operator(int) which does not exist
}
```

You see, we defined `<` and `>` pretty similarly, but `<` as a member and `>` as a free function. For the free function the implicit conversions are done, for member functions not.

To bring this to your example `int *` is not an object, hence, it cannot have a member functions. So the `operator[]` for `int *` is a basically a free function (this is not exactly correct, it is more ingrained in the language. But I think it is a useful model for thinking about it). Hence, we can call `operator[](A::operator int*(), int)`.

You cannot reproduce this behavior for object types, since `operator[]` cannot be defined as a free function (that's how the language is).